# Droid Naskh font and Arabic number 4

Tags: android, fonts, arabic

I'm using Droid Naskh font in my application to display Arabic characters. One of my users pointed out that the arabic number 4 `٤` displays as number 5 `٥`. I have attached a screenshot below of how it's appearing on the device (as well as the emulator).

This is the string:

```
<string name="num">٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩</string>
```

Output:

[image]

Why is this happening?

PS: I tried other fonts as well, yet this persists. I tried unicode `U+0664`, but it displays 5. This is weird.

Comment: where did you get your font from? I use droid naskh and I've never had this problem.

Comment: I got it from Google. But after a few tests with other fonts, I realized it's nothing to do with the font because when I use other fonts, it still displays the Arabic Indic numeral 4 as 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, figured it out. I was using the [ArabicReshaper](http://code.google.com/p/arabicreshaper/) class and there was a mistake for `U+0664`.

[This](http://code.google.com/p/arabicreshaper/source/browse/opensourceReshape/src/com/AzizHuss/ArabicRehaper/ArabicReshape.java#106):

```
{0x0664, 0x000B, 0x0665, 0x0664, 0x0664, 0x0664},
```

Should be:

```
{0x0664, 0x000B, 0x0664, 0x0664, 0x0664, 0x0664},
```